# How to generate a checksum for each installed application

Tags: android

By using the android package manager I can generate a list of all installed apps.
However, I can't find a way to generate checksums for each .apk file corresponding to a given installed app (ideally this would be done through an app running on a non-rooted device).

Is it possible to write an app that does this (even if the phone needs to be rooted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to directly access the APKs for installed apps on a non-rooted device, although you can get access to them if they're on the system partition.

I'm not sure quite what you want the checksums for - you can get the package signature and version information through [PackageManager.getPackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), which may be what you need.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that.
I'm using the checksum to uniquely identify an installed app that may not have come from the market (which, (based on my understanding) does not need to keep incremental version numbers))

Comment: The version numbers should come from AndroidManifest.xml, regardless of distribution mechanism. Of course, there's no guarantee that someone has bumped that (you don't need to for debug builds).